# AnimationUtils.loadAnimation в отдельном классе

Tags: java, android, анимация

При использовании кода в классе текущей *Activity* все работает:

```
Animation anim;
anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha_anim);
view.startAnimation(anim);
```

Когда пытаюсь реализовать тот же код в отдельном классе, среда подчеркивает `this` в параметрах `loadAnimation`:

```
class CustomAnimation implements Animation.AnimationListener {
    View v;
    void animation () {
        Animation anim;
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha_anim);
        anim.setAnimationListener(this);
        v.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Из документации Android: *Метод: loadAnimation (Context context, int id). Parameters: context - Application context used to access resources*

Таким образом сюда следует передать Application context. **Но как это сделать?** Пытался с помощью getApplicationContext(), но среда на это ругается тоже.

Comment: 1. передать `Context` в конструктор 2. получить Context из `View v` во втором случае это `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), v);`

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish 
**передать Context в конструктор** - как это правильно осуществить подскажите?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class CustomAnimation implements Animation.AnimationListener {
    private Context context;
    public CustomAnimation(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    void animation () {
        Animation anim;
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.alpha_anim);
        anim.setAnimationListener(this);
        v.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    ...
}
```

Только не понятно как вы инициализируете `v` у вас не полный листинг класса наверно

Думаю итоговый вариант будет такой

```
class CustomAnimation implements Animation.AnimationListener {
        private Context context;
        private View animatedView;
        public CustomAnimation(Context context, View view){
            this.context = context;
            this.animatedView = view;
        }
        void animation () {
            Animation anim;
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.alpha_anim);
            anim.setAnimationListener(this);
            animatedView.startAnimation(anim);
        }

        ...
    }
```

При создании объекта типа `CustomAnimation` передаете контекст и вьюху которую хотите анимировать. Если работаете в активити, в конструктор можно передать `this`, если в фрагменте получаем контекст из `getActivity()`
А вообще давайте больше кода и тогда вам ответят однозначно!

Comment: Нечаянно удалил инициализацию v из класса, вернул.

Comment: все равно не вижу инициализации. Вижу `View v;` и че, у вас будет исключение на этапе выполнения NP

Comment: собирался присвоить v ссылку в экземпляре этого класса

Comment: рекомендую вам в начале карьеры применять сразу примитивные приемы инкапсуляции :-)

Comment: В начале карьеры не могу уловить, что вы имеете ввиду?)

Answer (score 2):

например, можно передать так:

```
class CustomAnimation ...................  {
Context ctx;

CustomAnimation(Context ctx)
{
   this.ctx = ctx;
}

 void animation () {
        Animation anim;
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.ctx, R.anim.alpha_anim);
        anim.setAnimationListener(this);
        v.startAnimation(anim);
    }

........
};
```